# Meta Query value >= (current date) not working with ACF

Tags: wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a loop with ACF fields inside of it. What I am trying to do is to loop my custom post type, but when the date is already passed the loop has to NOT show the event that already happened.

My code is made as follows:

```
<?php
$today = date('Ymd');
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type'=>'rasweekenden',
  'post_status'=>'publish',
  'posts_per_page'=>5,
  'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'eventdatum',
        'value' => $today,
        'type' => 'DATE', // specify it for numeric values
        'compare' => '>='
      )
    ),
  'meta_key' => 'eventdatum',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'ASC',
));

if($posts)
{
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($posts as $post)


  $date_event = date("Ymd", strtotime(get_field('eventdatum', get_the_ID())));
  $date_today = date('Ymd');


  if ($date_event >= $date_today){

    {
    the_field('rasweekend_heading', $post->ID);
    }
}

    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

`eventdatum` is a ACF field assigned to my Custom Post type rasweekenden.
This is made with the Datepicker from ACF with a value output of `Ymd`.

I think it has something to do with my `meta_query` but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think `get_the_ID()` function will not work with `get_posts`

Comment: @ParthaviPatel Thank you for the quick reply. I am trying to fix this for 2 days already but i cannot find anything . Do you have any ideas?

Comment: have you tried removing `type` from the meta query?

Comment: @HowardE No success but good suggestion

Comment: You could also try to change to this `'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num'`

Comment: @HowardE Tried with no success

Comment: can you `var_dump($posts)` are you getting ANY results?

Comment: @HowardE did not think of that. Will do that ASAP.

Comment: @HowardE When i put the `var_dump` right after the foreach it outputs posts. But when i put it inside the `$date_today` it does not output anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since your query is getting posts.  I would remove the if statement from the loop, as you've already done this anyway on the query.

```php
if($posts) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        echo '<li>';
        the_field('rasweekend_heading', $post->ID);
        echo '</li>;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```